# Grid разные ряды, парные и непарные

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

Подскажите, возможно ли задать разные колонки для разных строк, находясь в одном блоке?
Структуру менять нельзя.

Прикрепил ссылку на кодпен

С гридами не много работал. По этому интересно, возможно ли такое.
Что бы каждый непарный ряд был как в примере, а каждый парный ряд наоборот, первый елемент ряда маленький, а второй больше.
Спасибо большое.

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid > div {
  background: blue;
  height: 60px;
  
}

.grid > div:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(even) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jukachu/pen/VwmbQdq)

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял речь идет не о "парном/непарном" ряде, а о "четном/нечетном". Похоже вы хотите сделать нечто подобное:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid > div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(5n+4) { 
  grid-row: auto / span 2; 
  background: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```